# Help with a task scheduling algorithm

Tags: java, priority-queue, job-scheduling

I am working on an application in which thousands of tasks associated 
with hundreds of devices, each task requiring, < 5ms to begin execution, and 
taking on average 100ms to complete.

The conditions are as such:

1. Each device can only process a single
   task at a time, e.g., one task must finish running on its assigned 
   device prior to subsequent task's being processeed.
2. The scheduler should be efficient. Currently, processing a given device's
   work queue takes longer than the sum of it's tasks.

Here is basic description of the current implementation:

Each device contains a work queue which is filled with tasks associated with 
that device.

When a task is enqueued, that device's work queue is placed into a
global run queue (a queue of queue's). The global run queue is consumed by a worker thread
which dequeue's the device's task objects, processes one, then places
the device queue at the back of the global run queue. When that given device
has been dequeued again, the worker thread checks to see if the task has completed,
if so, the next task is executed. This process continues, until all device queues
have been depleted of tasks in the global runqueue.

Any suggestions for improvements? Have I stated this clearly? If not, please let me know, and I'll do my best to clarify.

Thanks for taking the time to look this over. Regards.

Comment: Can a given task be processed by one and only one device, or can any device process any task?  What do you mean by "a task takes < 5ms to start executing"?  Do you mean that it must be started within 5ms?  (If not, how is this fact relevant?)

Comment: @Stephen - a task takes <5ms to begin executing, in that several steps precede task execution, e.g., the device has to be contacted... etc.

Comment: @Stephen - a given task, or set of tasks is associated with a unique device, so to answer your question: no, any device cannot process any task.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) together with a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  This gives you callback on completion, which you can use to submit subsequent jobs, and a managed threadpool of executors, which you can tweak to improve throughput.

I suggest you run your code through a profiler to see which threads are currently blocking (sounds like it will be your producer device threads).  I can recommend [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp), however its not free.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of the CompletionService interface; thank you. After reading the description, my current implementation is very similar to that of the ExecutorCompletionService. However, I'll test it out. Maybe it will decrease the queue processing time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your design is that only one task is run at a time, which means that any device is idle while any other device is in use.

Since there are hundreds of devices, it would probably not be a good idea to assign a thread to each of these devices, but a thread pool could very well be used.

Comment: The worker thread consuming the global run queue has access to a ExecutorService thread pool; so multiple devices are processing tasks. I agree, that a thread per device is the wrong approach. Thanks for your comments.